# how to change css with jquery and .each?

Tags: javascript, css

I have several div with the .item class and want to change the css if the id is 1

```
</div>

<div class="item" id="0">

</div>

$('.item').each(function(i){
        var estatus = $(this).attr('id');
        if (estatus == '1')
            // change only item with id = 1
    });
```

Comment: Just a pointer, but please never do `$(this).attr('id')` or `$(this).prop('id')`; just use `this.id`: it's faster, cheaper and available in every browser I'm aware of.

Comment: @DavidThomas: All browsers, full stop, and [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63534901) no later than 2003. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your selector...

```
$('#1').css('whatever', 'yep');
```

Please see the comments section to see why this works *in this scenario*, but you're gonna have bad time if selecting it in a stylesheet. I'd recommend using the method in [T.J.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225809/31671), because of jQuery ever switch to funnelling these calls through `querySelectorAll()`, it will blow up).

My recommendation is to *not use `id` attributes that start with a number*.

Comment: `#1` is an invalid selector. It works in jQuery, in isolation, because jQuery will convert `$("#1")` to `$(document.getElementById("1"))`, but it's invalid.

Comment: What @alex said.

But several things - first of all, a numeric id is not valid, and also more than one of the same id is not valid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just tried it in Chrome, jQuery appeared to select what I wanted.

Comment: @alex: Yes, but the selector is invalid, and it could stop working tomorrow.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [console](http://i.imgur.com/jGaQTa9.png) -  according to the relevant [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): *There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: is it not? I though under HTML5 the rules for valid `id`-names had relaxed to, pretty much, anything? Under CSS it's a pain to select, if the first character is a number, but in HTML5 valid?

Comment: @alex: Wrong spec. The relevant spec for CSS selectors is the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), not the HTML spec. It's quite true, HTML allows a wide range of values in `id`s that CSS requires be escaped.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Interesting that they would allow it as a HTML attribute to be invalid as a selector. Can you please link to relevant spec? I always like learning something new. :)

Comment: @alex: See above. To use a digit at the beginning of an ID selector in CSS *validly*, you must escape it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it now - so it's not *invalid* per se, it's just requires a convoluted selector in CSS. And it only works in jQuery because it detected an `id` and shortcutted to `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: @alex: No, `#1` is an invalid CSS selector, full stop. Try it with `querySelector`, for instance. If you want to select an `id` starting with a digit, you **must** escape it to be in-spec (and to work with browsers' built-in engines, reliably).

Comment: @itamar: *"first of all, a numeric id is not valid"* `id` values starting with digits (or even consisting entirely of digits) are completely valid. It's just if you want to select them in CSS, you have to jump through hoops.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the correction - I meant for this purpose. In general, not a good idea.

Comment: @itamar: Agreed, I never start `id` values with digits, too much of a pain. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, it's awkward to use `id` values starting with a digit; the simplest thing is to avoid using them.

But with what you have, you can do this:

```
$(".item[id='1']").css(/*...*/);
```

Just using `#1` as a selector may work in certain select situations provided they don't rely in CSS parsing, but is [invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). If you must have an `id` value starting with a digit, to use it with a CSS selector, you have to escape it. The escaped version of `#1` is `#\31`, which gets even more awkward when written as a JavaScript string: `$("#\\31").css(/*...*/);`.

But this works and is in-spec:

```
$("#\\31").css(/*...*/);
```

This works in jQuery as of the current version and is **not** in spec:

```
$("#1").css(/*...*/);
```

It could stop working at any time, however, as it's not in-spec, and breaks if you combine it with various things.

Comment: From what I've read, you should be quoting the value in the attribute selector.

Comment: @alex: Then [read more closely](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation). Not using quotes here is completely valid.

Comment: Was just reading that too. I wonder if that was relaxed recently or if my memory is just kaput. I'm *pretty sure* the jQuery attr selector documentation used to make the recommendation to quote the value, but it doesn't anymore.

Comment: @alex: jQuery never required quotes. But revisiting the CSS spec (as distinct from what jQuery supports), if the value starts with a digit, I'm not at all sure the spec *doesn't* require quotes around it! Because the value must be either *identifier* or *string*, and the rules for *identifier* are the very reason you have to escape `#1`. So for the specific case here, to be in-spec, I think you **do** need quotes! You wouldn't if it were `a`, but `1` is a different case (and of course, if it were `a`, you could use `#a`).

Comment: It never *required*, but it used to recommend.

Comment: @alex: Yes, jQuery used to recommend using quotes. jQuery API docs != CSS specification.